# Combining Angular directives, specifically a custom directive with ng-mousemove

Tags: angularjs

Ok this is a very basic question. **What I want is a directive with a canvas tag for a template, and events giving mouse/touch coordinates relative to the canvas.** I could just use jquery in the linking function, but everyone seems to think that's cheating. I know I don't have a crisp understanding of how angular directives play with each other on the same element, and image that would help a lot.

Comment: I'd suggest making a fiddle and coming back with a more specific question.  Give it a try yourself first.

Comment: At the risk of loosing more rep I'll by talking here, I got it work, but it doesn't feel right. What I'm doing atm is adding a function to controller scope from the link function, and then calling that from the directive I'm adding in the template. I don't feel like I should be cluttering the controller like that. But it works and namespacing should prevent any collisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll take a stab at it.  If this isn't what you're after, please clarify.

What follows is a primitive directive that compiles into a canvas, and handle mouse move and mouse click events.

The directive looks like:

```
app.directive('myCanvas', function () {

return {
  replace: true,
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'my-canvas-template.html',
  link: function (scope, elem, attr) {

  }
 };    
});
```

The template looks like:

```
<div>
<canvas style="border:1px solid #000000;width:'400px';height:'400px" ng-mousemove="moved = moved + 1" ng-click="clicked = clicked + 1">
</canvas>
<p>Mouse moves: {{ moved }}</p>
<p>Mouse clicks: {{ clicked }}</p>
</div>
```

See it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Te5xykc01dDCJZQsEO0?p=preview).  Hope this helps ...

Comment: Thanks for that. I did get the angular team's ngMousemove example working.

I think the issue was that I wanted the function call in the attr value to be "on the directive" some how. Right now they evaluate in the controller scope so you have to clutter your scope with random methods from directives, and I just don't like the feel of that, but I guess thats just how it is